# How integrated is Collada to OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es, collada

All over where I read about the Collada file format I see some hint as to how integrated Collada is to OpenGL ES - or the other way.  How integrated is it really?  I suspect not, but are there functions that directly work with Collada files? - or even parts of Collada files?  Or do I need to create my own parser from the ground up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your own parser, OpenGL or OpenGL ES doesn't have any model/mesh loading functionality, that's the developer's responsability.

Comment: Thanx!  I don't mind creating my own parser - I just mind doing it and then finding out OpenGL ES has functions for it.  Hehe...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is about COLLADA FX - a 'meta' way of describing shaders. See "How does Collada FX integrate with OpenGL ES and OpenGL?" in the [faq](http://www.khronos.org/collada/faq/). The other stuff you still have to do yourself or find a library for.